# Is there a way to decode a tf.Summary protobuf object and access its values in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow

So far I've figured out that the protobuf header for the summaries is defined here:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.2/tensorflow/core/framework/summary.proto

Answer (score 1):

This is possible using the `tf.Summary()` class:

```
summary_string = sess.run(summary)
summary_proto = tf.Summary().FromString(summary_string)
for entry in summary_proto.value:
    print(entry.tag)
```